# Running script from powershell prompt

Tags: python, powershell, environment

I have installed python 2.7.4 in the directory C:\python27, and I have edited my user environment variable to include:

```
Python       C:\python27;C:\python27\Tools\Scripts\pyscripts
```

(`pyscripts` is a directory containing my python programs)

Using PowerShell 2009, from the prompt `PS C:\>`, I type:

```
python trigrams.py
```

This results in the following error message;

```
The term 'python ' is not recognized as the name of  a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path name is correct and try again.
    *python <<<< chunks.py
    +CategoryInfo  :ObjectNotFound:<python:String> [].CommandNotFoundException
    +FullyQualifiedErrorID  :CommandNotFouindException
```

What is causing this?

Comment: Please check if `$env:Path` includes `C:\python27`.

Answer (score 0):

Your PATH variable doesn't include C:\python27